# Как сделать вывод текущего времени с поочерёдным обновлением секунд, минут, часов?

Tags: javascript

Должно выводиться текущее время на экран, но обновляться должны не все элементы, а только необходимая часть. То есть, допустим время 14:23:44 - в доме должны обновляться только секунды, когда дойдёт до 14:23:59 - и минуты, и секунды. Если же время допустим 20:59:59, то должны обновиться и секунды, и минуты, и часы. Подскажите как можно реализовать подобную логику с помощью setInterval на чистом js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FRONT-END LAB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="current_time">
                <span>Current time:</span>
                <span id="ctime_hours" class="ctime_hours"></span>
                <span id="ctime_minutes" class="ctime_minutes"></span>
                <span id="ctime_seconds" class="ctime_seconds"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>  
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: А что пробовали вы для этого? В чем возникла проблема?

Comment: @SwaD Попробовал написать логику, но написав понял, что при некоторых изменениях она бы больше подошла для секундомера) https://jsbin.com/zisakoduya/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @wavy_ стартуйте не с нуля а от текущей даты

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kibunixisi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @wavy_
https://jsbin.com/kibunixisi/edit?html,js,output вот тут секунды, часы и минуты не обновляются если они не равны

Comment: @Jackson спасибо, всё проще чем я думал)

Comment: сорри - последняя ссылка должна была быть примерно вот такой - https://jsbin.com/kibunixisi/9/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```
const currentDate = new Date();
let seconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
let minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
let hours = currentDate.getHours();

setStartTime(seconds, minutes, hours);

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

function updateTime() {
  if (seconds < 59) {
    seconds++;
  } else {
    seconds = 0;
    
    if (minutes < 59) {
      minutes++;
    } else {
      minutes = 0;
      
      if (hours < 23) {
        hours++;
      } else {
        hours = 0;
      }
      
      setHours(hours);
    }
    
    setMinutes(minutes);
  }
  
  setSeconds(seconds);
}

function setSeconds(seconds) {
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('ctime_seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
}

function setMinutes(minutes) {
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('ctime_minutes').innerHTML = minutes;
}

function setHours(hours) {
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('ctime_hours').innerHTML = hours;
}

function setStartTime(seconds, minutes, hours) {
  setHours(hours);
  setMinutes(minutes);
  setSeconds(seconds);
}
```

если все же надо самому считать секунды минуты, часы - вот